# Hearing with head upside down

Tags: hearing

When doing some stretching exercises and listening to music, I noticed that when my head is upside down for 10sec or more, my hearing changes.

It is very gradual and I am losing the low frequencies. At the same time, I am feeling nose congestion coming.

Upon coming back up, my hearing is fully restored almost instantly.

What is this phenomenon due to?